# Resgatar valores do Cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, cookies

Boa tarde tenho uma aplicação em MVC que gera alguns cookies, gostaria de saber se é possível resgatar esses cookies através de uma Api, pois tentei e infelizmente não consegui.

Código gerado para a api:

```
[Route("ResgataCookie")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult ResgataCookie()
{
    string test = "";
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["RMACookies"] != null)
    {
        test = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["RMACookies"].Value;
    }

    return Ok(test);
}
```

Segue imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Os Cookies na WebAPI podem ser acessados utilizando o `Request.Headers.GetCookies`

Veja a documentação em https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies

Segue exemplo abaixo

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ResgataCookie")]
public IHttpActionResult ResgataCookie()
{
  var cookies = Request.Headers.GetCookies().FirstOrDefault();

  if (cookies == null || !cookies.Cookies.Any(p => p.Name == "RMACookies"))
    return NotFound();

  var item = cookies.Cookies.First(p => p.Name == "RMACookies").Value;

  return Ok(item);
}
```

Comment: Olá amigo fiz dessa forma, também mas o mesmo me retorna nulo. os cookies são gerados em uma aplicação MVC padrão, mas estou tentando acessar os cookies através da api e infelizmente retornam em branco.

Comment: Você esta tentando acessar os cookies de outra aplicação?

Lembrando que os cookies são armazenados por domínios e subdominios então se forem diferentes você não vai ter acesso mesmo.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Danilo.